# Why is random.choice so imbalanced?

Tags: python, random

So I have been writing some very random experimental code, and I found the results I got kind of puzzling.

This is my code

```py
from random import choice

class A:


    def __init__(self, l):
        parsed = iter(l)

        self.include = next(parsed) == "+"
        self.l = list(parsed)



    def get(self, l):
        rt = self.l
        if self.include:
            rt += l
        return choice(rt)



a = A("+abcd")

d = dict()
for key in "abcdef":
    d[key] = 0

for i in range(100000):
    d[a.get(["e", "f"])] += 1

print(d)
```

I expected that code to output a random but somewhat even distribution of choices. Something like this:

```py
{'a': 16678, 'b': 16539, 'c': 16759, 'd': 16584, 'e': 16631, 'f': 16809}
```

But the actual output is this:

```py
{'a': 3, 'b': 4, 'c': 7, 'd': 3, 'e': 49588, 'f': 50395}
```

I mean, it is random, but if that was for real I might as well have won the lottery 10 times by now.

So, what exactly is going on here? Why does the `random.choice` function prefer to choose `"e"` and `"f"` so much over the others?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`random.choice` is fine. You're just not choosing from the options you think you are. In `get`:

```
        rt = self.l
        if self.include:
            rt += l
```

you're not copying `self.l`. Every `rt += l` is appending to the same list object, so that list ends up with a gazillion `'e'`s and `'f'`s in it, and those get picked most of the time.

To avoid this, you can copy `self.l` up front:

```
        rt = self.l[:]
        if self.include:
            rt += l
```

or you can use `+` instead of `+=`, since `+` builds a new list instead of mutating the left-hand side:

```
        rt = self.l
        if self.include:
            rt = rt + l
```

Comment: I guess I will erase the whole "`a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`" out of my head.